# Why is setting my widget option evaluating to an object instead of being passed as a key and value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've created (or am trying to create) a jQuery UI widget using the widget factory and have set up my `_setOptions` method this way as found here: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137708/How%20to%20use%20jQuery%20UI%

```
_setOptions: function (key, value) {
    if (this.options[key] !== value) {
        this.options[key] = value;
        this._update();
    }
},
```

This is my options object:

```
 options: {
            title: 'Legend',
            colors: ['#0000CC', '#6600CC', '#009900', '#990000', '#6600FF', '#CCFF00', '#FF9900', '#000000', '#FFFFFF', '#00FF00'],
            items: undefined
        }
```

However, when I pass in a new title value for my legend widget, I am getting an object for `key` instead of a `key` and `value` in `_setOptions`. `value` comes in undefined, for the record.

```
$('#myLegend').legend('option', 'title', 'New Title');
```

[image: The key object]

My expectations were this:

```
key==='title'
value==='New Title'
```

If there some common misconception I'm missing or can anyone think of why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_setOptions` method does get called with an object for the first argument, it contains key/value pairs of all the options changed.

http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_setOptions

what you probably meant to use was `_setOption` rather than `_setOptions`

Comment: Dammit. Instead of accepting blame, I will place blame on the fact today is Monday. Thanks, Kevin.